# Is the T-jove metro ticket in Barcelona valid for 25 years old people?

Tags: trains, tickets, spain, barcelona

From February on I will spend half a year in Barcelona and I'm trying to figure out which metro ticket suits best to me. I found the T-Joven Ticket which costs 80 Euro and is valid 90 days. It says, it is a ticket for "under 25s". https://www.tmb.cat/en/barcelona-fares-metro-bus/single-and-integrated/t-jove I couldn't find more precise information and I am 25. Is this ticket valid for me or not?

Thank you,
Joshua

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no, you have to buy it before your 25th birthday. But you can use it while you are over 25 if you bought it and validated your first trip before you turned 25.

> **T-jove for 1 zone**
>
> ...
>
> The use of the T-jove transport card is upheld throughout the validity of the card, even if the user has turned 25 during such period, as long as documentation is provided as proof that the user was under age 25 when the card was purchased and at the time of its first use.
>
> https://t-mobilitat.atm.cat/web/t-mobilitat/suports-i-titols/titols

Comment: Thank you very much!